# Where to get graphs to test my search algorithms against?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, data-sets, benchmarking

I am implementing a set of path finding algorithms such as Dijkstra's, Depth First, etc.

At first I used a couple of self made graphs, but now I'd like to take the challenge a bit further and thus I'm looking for either

1. graphs used in benchmarks;
2. graphs of real world cities (or a way to download that kind of info off google maps, or any other kind of source, if possible).

I'd like those sources to either have or allow me to easily create frontiers such that I can try my algorithms for different sized sets of graphs, if possible.

I'm looking for simple solutions, as I'd prefer not to be diverted from main goal (compare a set of different algorithms), so I'd need a quick way to convert that graph data into my own format (basically, a set of connected `(x, y)` points).

To be more concrete, what I'm looking for are 2D cyclic graphs. If those graphs reflect real world city streets (taking into consideration one-way streets, two-way streets, etc, better yet!).

Comment: There's the open graph archive: http://www.graph-archive.org/doku.php?id=start
and a paper explaining the project:
http://arxiv.org/abs/1109.1465

Comment: Welcome! Have you generated (large) sets of graphs according to several random distributions? (PS: You might want to choose a username different from the system default so you are more recognisable. :))

Comment: @Raphael Random graphs often don't make representative test cases for real world graphs: these tend to be [complex networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_network).

Comment: @Gilles: They make for better (i.e. large-scale, random, reproducable) lab tests than "I created 5 graphs per hand", still.

Comment: 1. [Data for testing graph algorithms](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/23748/where-on-the-internet-i-can-find-database-of-graphs)
2. [Data for testing graph algorithms](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/739/data-for-testing-graph-algorithms)

Comment: @joe / Pratik - why not posting as an answer?

Comment: @RanG. [An answer should not be just a link](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Gilles, I didn't mean posting the comments as-is, but rather (using your link:) "A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link". Currently, there is no option to comment on those links, and vote on them. I'm sure some of those links are very useful and answer the question asked, but nobody can upvote the good ones (in a meaningful way).

Comment: @RanG. Then post an answer with those links and the requisite explanation.

Comment: @Gilles that would be very rude towards Joe and Pratik.

Comment: @Joe The first website you linked to appears to be dead and replaced with malware.

Answer (score 17):

Search the inter-webs.

[SNAP](http://snap.stanford.edu/) is a set of networks hosted by a prof at Stanford. Several real world examples in a variety of settings.

[Net Wiki](http://netwiki.amath.unc.edu/) is hosted by a UNC math prof., again several links to real datasets as well as links to other data resources.

[OpenFlights](http://openflights.org/data.html) Has airports and routes between them (spatial network).

[OpenStreetMap](http://downloads.cloudmade.com/) user edited network of roads for most of the world. You can also download subsets (e.g. just roads in Ohio, or just highways in North America). Format is in xml, not super easy to parse, but its a real world ~2d cyclic network.

There are several other resources as well, you'll just have to dig a little.

Answer (score 2):

I've been visiting all the links provided by Nick. They do look wonderful indeed and I have added all those sites to my bookmarks. Hope that the following link especially designed to test search algorithms suits your needs as well:

[Pathfinding Benchmarks](http://www.movingai.com/benchmarks) by Nathan Sturtevant. It contains various maps from different video games and also other artificial benchmakrs such as mazes and graphs with random obstacles.

If you are, in particular, interested in this sort of domains, then you might want to take part in the Grid-Based Path Planning Competition next year (the results of the first edition of the competition are available at [GPPC 2012](http://movingai.com/GPPC/))

Cheers,