# Algorithms for graph generation using given properties

Tags: algorithms, graphs, sampling

There may be a large number of algorithms proposed for generating graphs satisfying some common properties (e.g., clustering coefficient, average shortest path length, degree distribution, etc).

My question concerns a specific case: I want to generate a few *undirected regular* graphs (i.e., every node in these graphs has the same number of neighbors) with different clustering coefficients and average shortest path lengths. More generally, by fixing a degree distribution, I want to generate graphs with different clustering coefficients and average shortest path lengths.

I wonder what are the well-known algorithms for doing this (or in fact, is there any?), and what are the recommended software for the same purpose?

Comment: See also the question [Generating inputs for random-testing graph algorithms?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2952/generating-inputs-for-random-testing-graph-algorithms/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no general algorithms for your problem but what one usually does (for graphs of small orders) is

1. Use [nauty](http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/nauty/) to generate graphs satisfying some rough constraints (you can make nauty generate only (bi)connected graphs, regular graphs, triangle/quadrangle free graphs,..)
2. Use an external program to extract only the graphs you need with respect to some additional  properties that you want.

You can do both 1 and 2 in [sage](http://www.sagemath.org/)! For example consider that you want to generate all connected 5-regular graphs of order 20 that have average distance 10 (Wiener index??) and some clustering coefficient. You do the following

```
for G in graphs.nauty_geng(" 20 -c -d5 -D5" ):
    if G.wiener_index() == 10 and G.clustering_coeff() == SOMETHING:
       print G.adjacency_matrix()
```

Let me know if you need some more specific answers related to sage.